# Bash paste function: Paste columns from different files if they match one column

Tags: bash, paste

I have files formatted like this

```
1 x
2 y
3 z
...
```

I want to create a master file like this

```
1 x a g
2 y b h
3 z c f
```

I know the paste command in bash can be used to paste columns, but my problem is that I don't know if the line numbers and column 1 values are equal for every file, and some files differ in length.

I could cave man my way in perl, but I'm trying to learn shell script. Thanks all for the love!

Comment: Could you tell us how you'd do it in Perl?

Comment: You'll need to show us the files.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2816090/3076724

Comment: You can probably use repeated applications of the `join` program to build up the master file one original file at a time